# Reload CollectionviewCell inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell inside which I have added **UICollectionViewCell** ( for horizontal scrolling).

If there is no internet I am showing a blank view. What I wanna do is when a user connects to the internet I should be able to show data.
Right now it shows randomly and 2 cells out of 3 are not visible at all.
I am using notification whether the user came in foreground and reloading table data. Here is my structure of table cell and collection view cell.

Code :

**ViewController.swift :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

**CategoryRow.swift**

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        return cell
    }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

}
```

**VideoCell.swift**

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: make sure you are hooking delegate and datasource of collectionView to ViewController in storyboard

Comment: viewcontroller ? I think it should be hooking to table cell ?

Comment: you need to add collectionview deleagte and data source into tableview cell. and then reload collectionview in awaknib of tableview cell .

Comment: awakeFromNib is called for one time only. @Hitesh

Comment: ok. make func in tableviewCell class and in that set delegate and datasource of collectionview and reload collectionview, that function call  in tableview cellforRow method, hop this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In `UITableViewDataSource` method reload `UICollectionView`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DashboardTableViewCell

       cell.collectionViewNeel.reloadData()

        return cell

    }
```